# Any way to fix the overlapping of the button and the text?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button on the right in a cell and text as well. The text overlaps the button. I want the text to go to the next line before it touches the button. How would I do that?

[image]

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileMusicCell



    cell.customtitle.text = ret[indexPath.row]
    cell.customartist.text = ter[indexPath.row]
    cell.customtitle.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 22)
    cell.customtitle.textColor =  UIColorFromRGB("4A90E2")
    cell.customartist.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 16)
    cell.customartist.textColor =  UIColor.blackColor()


       cell.playbutton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.playbutton.addTarget(self, action: "playmusic:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)




    cell.contentView.addSubview(playButton)


    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return cell
}

  func playmymusic(sender: UIButton!) {

    let playButtonrow = sender.tag

    print(ret[playButtonrow])
    print(ter[playButtonrow])
}
```

Comment: have you tried reseting the constraints of the button and reinserting them based on the location of the button? I had a similar problem with a navigation bar and a view and after an afternoon of searching i found this was the only solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: it's kinda bad coding to have `playButton.frame = CGRectMake(230, 20, 100, 100)`, and what i mean is you take no advantage of autolayout. If user changes devices issues will happen

Comment: This code has a logic flaw - every time the cell is dequeued the `playButton` will be added to the cell.  You will end up with many, many copies of the button added as you scroll the tableview. A far superior method would be to create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and use autolayout.

Comment: I created a custom cell, and know there is no overlap :D, but I lose my function for the button. This is the custom cell file http://puu.sh/lhgk0/fe780cf275.png. How will I change the playButton addTarget and .tag so that it corresponds to the new customcell playbutton?

Comment: create an `IBAction` in the view controller where you have implemented the `dataSource` and `delegate` methods of your `tableview` and attach it to your button in the storyboard.

Comment: How would I attach the button to the view controller if the cell is connected to a custom class?

Comment: I updated my code, but nothing is happening when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You can set frame for your uilabel and uibutton, like :

```
cell.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width - playButton.frame.size.with - cell.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.detailTextLabel.frame.height)
```

But, i think you should create a custom uitableviewcell for yourself, in there you can use autolayout, it better